# Web socket item remove convention

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

I am implementing a WebSocket client to display a list of items synchronized with the server state. I am using Spring on the backend and AngularJS for the front-end. I have gone through many examples and so far all discuss how to add items on the client side. I am however wondering if there is a convention on how to handle both additions *and removals*. I was thinking about using `STOMP` and subscribing to `add` and `remove topics`. Are there any established alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a perfect fit for the new [Spring Sync](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-sync), which provides synchronization based on a [differential synchronization](https://neil.fraser.name/writing/sync/eng047-fraser.pdf) algorithm and JSON patch so changes to an object can be tracked and synchronized with other objects.

Check out the [Differential Sync and JSON Patch](http://www.slideshare.net/briancavalier/differential-sync-and-json-patch-s2-gx-2014) presentation from SpringOne2GX 2014 and the [GitHub samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-sync-samples) (specially *scores* which uses WebSocket).

Comment: thanks for the great link! I have the feeling it might be an overkill in my particular use case as I will only be adding and removing items from a list, but I will consider it.

Comment: Always consider the use case, maybe having notifications when an item has been created / deleted will be enough for you, but if this more like a cross-cutting concern, you might want to consider Spring Sync

Answer (score 0):

In case you're asking about idiomatic approaches to implement RPC style of API with request-reply messages in Spring STOMP I recommend using @SubscribeMapping annotated methods. These destinations look like real broker's "topics", so you can subscribe to them, but their subscriptions last only until response is delivered. Here's more on @SubscribeMapping: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-handle-annotations